# Getting an error saying a prop is not a function, and that it is undefined

Tags: react-native

Getting an error on the ios simulator saying a prop is not a function, and that it is undefined

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CGpn.png)

Function I am calling,

```
addNewTodo = show => {
 this.setState({
  new_todo: show
});
};
```

---

```
render() {
const { new_todo } = this.state;
return (
  <Container style={styles.ViewStyle}>
    <Header>
      <Body>
        <Title style={styles.TextStyle}>All Todos</Title>
      </Body>
    </Header>
    <Content>
      {new_todo && (
        <AddToDo onPress={this.saveToDoData} onCancel={this.addNewTodo} />
      )}
    </Content>
    <Fabulous onAddNewTodo={this.addNewTodo} />
  </Container>
);
}
```

Fab I am calling,

```
export default class Fabulous extends React.Component {
render() {
const { onAddNewToDo } = this.props;
return (
  <Container>
    <Fab
      style={{ backgroundColor: "#05a557" }}
      position="bottomRight"
      onPress={() => onAddNewToDo(true)}
    >
      <Icon name="add" />
    </Fab>
  </Container>
);
}
}
```

**[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CGpn.png)**

**[Link to Code](https://gist.github.com/romasch94/676968f5e6a741920b54e39ab92881d7)**

New to react and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have any props named onAddNewToDo? Can you show all the code?

Comment: @HaiderAli I have added the screenshot of the relevant code, the prop is seen here, <Fabulous onAddNewTodo={this.addNewTodo} />. If the whole code will be helpful I can zip it and provide a link over here.

Comment: Please don't post code and errors as images. Just paste them as text instead.

Comment: @duplode Sorry about that. I have since uploaded the code on Github.

Comment: Check name of the functions: you pass to props it with name `onAddNewTo*do*`, but calling in component with name `onAddNewTo*Do*`;

Comment: @AlexShtromberg  That was it. Was having a hard time figuring out what was wrong. Thanks a lot!